# Linq where condition not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to filter all surname as "Peter"

But its not filtering instead it list all rows without filter

What wrong i am doing?

```
if (pagedCollection != null)
{
    do
    {
        List<IUser> usersList = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();

        usersList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Surname) && x.Surname.Contains("Peter")).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (IUser user in usersList)
        {
            userList.Add((User) user);
        }
        pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
    } 
    while (pagedCollection != null);
}
```

Comment: Why is this in a do while? this should just be an `If` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line returns a *single user* which `SurName` contains `"Peter"`, because of `FirstOrDefault`:

```
usersList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Surname) && x.Surname.Contains("Peter")).FirstOrDefault();
```

But you don't store the result anywhere. it doesn't "filter" the original list as this:

```
usersList = usersList 
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Surname) && x.Surname.Contains("Peter"))
    .ToList();
```

Actually this query also doesn't filter the original list, instead it creates a new and finally reassigns this new list to the old variable. So the effect is similar to filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Where returns an IEnumeable that you currently take the first instance of and then you throw that away.

Try this

```
if (pagedCollection != null)
{
    do
    {
        List<IUser> usersList = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
        usersList = usersList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Surname) && x.Surname.Contains("Peter"));
        pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
    } 
    while (pagedCollection != null);
}
```

Comment: Please read code before posting answers.  Answering questions are not about fixing 1 problem blindly,   If they are trying to get a filtered list of Peter.  1. Why are you re-adding that back to the original users list?  2. Why are you doing this in a do while loop instead of just returning the list?

Answer (score 1):

After applying filtering using where condition on your user list, you are working on original user list and not working on resulting list after filtering. Hence it contains all users every time.

```
var filteredUserList = usersList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Surname) 
                                             && x.Surname.Contains("Peter"));
```

This should display filtered users.

Also, FirstOrDefault will filter only one user satisfying filter criteria, you should remove it, and check for nulls before starting foreach loop.